# Slider animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm struggling to change the animation of my slider, every time I try to change something, the slider disappears. I want a slider right animation instead of fade.

I have researched, but nothing fits what I want.

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider .fadeimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: galeria 9s infinite;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 95% at 50% 0%);
}

.fadeimg:nth-child(1) {}

.fadeimg:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fadeimg:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes galeria {
  33.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="img/dummy-640x310-1.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="img/dummy-640x310-2.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="img/dummy-640x310-3.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.slider-container {
  width:640px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slider {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slider .fadeimg {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 47.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  opacity: 1;
  animation: galeria 9s infinite;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 95% at 50% 0%);
}

.fadeimg:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fadeimg:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

.fadeimg:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes galeria {
  0% {
    /*opacity: 1;*/
    transform: translate(0%,0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-100%,0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-200%,0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="slider">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x310/0000ff/fff" alt="">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x310/ff0000/fff" alt="">
  <img class="fadeimg" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x310/00ff00/fff" alt="">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, I change the width to 100% to be responsive, and it fades again... Where does the fade come from when there is no fade property?

Thank you btw!

Comment: Which element's width are you trying to change?

Comment: The code above assumes that you want only one image to be visible at a time, and that when the next image slides in, the previous image is no longer visible. For this to happen, the slider container should not exceed an image's width. Otherwise you will see portions of the other images too.
If you are trying to make slider-container responsive. Add max-width:80%; to slider-container as well as fadeImg